# How to list folders where superuser has permissions on Windows Server

Tags: windows, permissions, command

Is there a way on windows server to list the folders where an superuser has permissions like

c:list permissions "superuser" ?

I would expect following result

c:\dddd\sfsf\dfsf
d:\sdfsdf\dfsf\fsdfsf

Thanks.

Comment: Something like [CACLS.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html) or [PERMS.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/perms.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a way. 
The magical tools is **subinacl**. It works well.